# Advanced graph visualisation library for C#

Tags: library, c#, data-visualization, graphs

I'm looking for an **advanced** graph visualisation library for C# with the following features:

- Adding nodes and edges programmatically & dynamically (*i.e.* I shouldn't have to construct the graph from CSV, or JSON every time I add a node and an edge)
- Being able to interact with the graph, that is, to **click** (single, double and/or *right*) on the nodes and edges, to **hover** (so that I can show a tooltip), to **select** single or multiple nodes and/or edges.
- Custom styling for nodes and edges, such as border width & colour, shape, colour (of the object), label, label formatting (bold, italic etc.)
- Automatic layout

Coming from the front-end programming, many of the features above are indeed a *subset* of what many JavaScript libraries (such as [vis.js](http://visjs.org/), [Sigma js](http://sigmajs.org/), ...) do offer with a dead easy API.

I have looked at [Graphviz4Net](https://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/), [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/), [graphviznet](http://code.google.com/p/graphviznet/) but none of them offers anything near, and worse, seem to lack documentation that I am not even sure what they can offer me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Diagram for WPF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/diagram) supports creating any kind of diagram with nodes and connectors.

Adding nodes and edges programmatically & dynamically: Supported
Being able to interact with the graph: Supported
Custom styling for nodes and edges: Supported
Automatic layout: Organization Chart, Hierarchical Tree and Radial Tree layouts are [supported](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdiagram/automatic-layouts).

[image: Diagram WPF with animated connectors]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.